# Browserify - Bundle loads, but doesn't work afterwards

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

Before you ask, yes I've been using Browserify multiple times, but for some reason it just won't work this time.

**The problem:**

When I load up the website, bundle.js will only be executed once, then be ignored for the rest of the time. - Require is not the problem, since I tried to Console.log some require code, which worked, but afterwards, anything done by the user won't be executed.

As you can see in my code, I'm trying to execute registerHref() onclick of my button, which works when I'm not using bundle.js, but as soon as I'm doing this with my bundle, it's like it's being completely ignored. I will get an error which says: `Uncaught ReferenceError: registerHref is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick` - But when I try to console.log the function on window.onload - it works as it should.

**My HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header" style="border-style: solid; text-align: center;">
        <button id="register" onclick="registerHref()">Register</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**My Javascript:**

```
function registerHref() {
    window.location.href = "./register.html"
}
```

**What I did:**

- I made my bundle using: `browserify main.js > bundle.js` <- Usually works fine

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that after the code gets compiled the function isn't attached to the `window` object but instead is executed within a different scope.

You have basically two options here:

1. Attach the `registerHref` function to the window object (not recommended):

```js
function registerHref() {
  window.location.href = "./register.html"
}

window.registerHref = registerHref;
```

2. Create an event listener in your JS code and remove the `onclick` attribute from your HTML (recommended):

```js
function registerHref() {
  window.location.href = "./register.html"
}
    
document.getElementById('register').addEventListener('click', registerHref);
```